# Plot Tendency on Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka, polyline

Does anyone know a way in which i can AUTOMATICALLY plot a "tendency" line for an output of a visualization in WEKA? (See images)

[image]

What i want to achieve:

[image]

In the second image, I just plot the polyline on my own which is very open to bias and error.

What i want to achieve is a line which describes where the point may actually lie. Like a tendency to do so (as the approximation in the 2nd image)